# unsupported operand type(s) for |=: 'list' and 'list'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, spi

I am having trouble with some code for an AMT22 encoder. I am getting the following error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |=: 'list' and 'list'.
I know I cant do an operation like this on two lists, but I don't know how to declare currentPosition as uint16 as I would like too.

I am using python on a Raspberry Pi 4 B through which the encoders communicate by SPI, so I am using spidev library.

Here is all the code with the error attached at the bottom.

```
import time
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import spidev
import math
import array as arr

BAUDRATE = 115200
AMT22_NOP = 0x00
AMT22_RESET = 0x60
AMT22_ZERO = 0x70

NEWLINE = 0x0A
TAB = 0x09

RES12 = 12
ENC_1 = 8
SPI_MOSI = 10
SPI_MISO = 9
SPI_SCLK = 13

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(SPI_MOSI, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(SPI_MISO, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(SPI_SCLK, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ENC_1, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(ENC_1, True)

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 0)
spi.max_speed_hz = 500
binaryArray = arr.array('d', [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])

def spiWriteRead(sendByte, encoder, releaseLine):
    GPIO.output(encoder, False)
    sleep(0.000003)
     data = spi.xfer([sendByte])
#     spi.writebytes([sendByte])
#     data = spi.readbytes(16)
    sleep(0.000003)
    GPIO.output(encoder, releaseLine)
    return data

def getPositionSPI(encoder):
    currentPosition = spiWriteRead(AMT22_NOP, encoder, False)
    sleep(0.000003)
    currentPosition |= spiWriteRead(AMT22_NOP, encoder, True)
    for i in range(16):
        binaryArray[i] = (0x01) & (currentPosition >> i)
    if ((binaryArray[15] is math.factorial(binaryArray[13]**binaryArray[11]**binaryArray[9]**binaryArray[7]**binaryArray[5]**binaryArray[3]**binaryArray[1])) and (binaryArray[14] is math.factorial(binaryArray[12]**binaryArray[10]**binaryArray[8]**binaryArray[6]**binaryArray[4]**binaryArray[2]**binaryArray[0]))):
        currentPosition & 0x3FFF
    else:
        currentPosition & 0xFFFF

    if (currentPosition != 0xFFFF):
        currentPosition >> 2

    return currentPosition

try:
    while True:
        attempts = 0
        encoderPosition = getPositionSPI(ENC_1)

        while (encoderPosition == 0xFFFF and attempts < 3):
            attempts += 1
            encoderPosition = getPositionSPI(ENC_1)

            if (encoderPosition == 0xFFFF):
                print("Encoder 0 error. Attempts: ")
                print(attempts)
            else:
                print("Encoder 0: ")
                print(encoderPosition)

            sleep(0.5)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Ctl C pressed - ending program")

GPIO.cleanup()
close()
print("Done")




Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/AMT22.py", line 66, in <module>
    encoderPosition = getPositionSPI(ENC_1)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/AMT22.py", line 50, in getPositionSPI
    currentPosition |= spiWriteRead(AMT22_NOP, encoder, True)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |=: 'list' and 'list'
```

Any help would be appreciated,
Thank you!

Comment: What *exactly* do you get back from `spiWriteRead` each time? What *exactly* do you want to end up in `currentPosition`?

Comment: you mean currentPosition != spiWriteRead(AMT22_NOP, encoder, True)?
please change this currentPosition |= spiWriteRead(AMT22_NOP, encoder, True)
to this currentPosition != spiWriteRead(AMT22_NOP, encoder, True)

Comment: @bro no, OP wants to do some kind of modification, not a comparison. `x != y` on a line by itself wouldn't be useful.

Comment: To be clear, you're using this library? https://github.com/doceme/py-spidev

Comment: `spiWriteRead()` apparently returns a list, not an integer.

Comment: As an aside: `binaryArray[15] is math.factorial(...)` Do not use `is` to compare numeric values. It does not do what you want.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel, Yes I am using that library spidev and thank you ill look into the 'is'!

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, the method `xfer` returns a list of bytes and so does your `spiWriteRead` function.

I am going to assume that for your calculation you want to take the first two bytes from that list and convert them to a 16 bit unsigned integer in little-endian format.

You can use the `struct` module to do that:

```
import struct

currentPosition |= struct.unpack('<H', bytearray(spiWriteRead(AMT22_NOP, encoder, True)))[0]
```

What this line does is as follows:

1. convert the list `spiWriteRead` returns in to an array of bytes so `unpack` can process it.
2. Unpack the array in to a single unsigned short ('H' formatting letter) in little-endian ('<' format sign) byte order.
3. Because `unpack` always returns a tuple, take the first element ([0]) which will be an integer, thus you can do the `|` (or) operation on it.

For more information on working with binary data in Python read the [`struct` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html).

**Edit:**
Looking again at the code, and considering the OP comment to this answer, it may be that the `spiReadWrite` function returns one byte at a time, and the `or` operation is to combine the high and low byte of the `uint16`.

If this is the case, there is no need to use the `struct` module, only extract the single member of the list that contains the actual byte value.

Note however, the result must be bit shifted not simply or'ed to get the correct value.

Here is how the code would look in that case:
(this again assumes we are working in little-endian, so least significant byte is read first)

```
currentPosition = spiWriteRead(AMT22_NOP, encoder, False)[0]
sleep(0.000003)
currentPosition |= spiWriteRead(AMT22_NOP, encoder, True)[0] << 8
```

Note the only difference from the original code is adding the list index `[0]` and in the second call shifting all the bits by 8 places to make them the higher byte of a 2 byte int.

Comment: Thank you Lev M. So I am looking at what you sent and have never used struct module before but it looks like it will do want I need.  Taking what you have there word for word and plugging it into my code results in a 'struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 2 bytes'. I am looking into this but if you end up replaying before it is solved it would be much appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @AveryTurley it looks like you are not getting enough bytes back back from the function to build a uint16. How many bytes do you expect the function to return? Does it return one byte of the uint16 each time and you are trying to combine them? If that is the case, I can show you a simpler code to do it.

Comment: +1 if you want to make use of the data you get back from the API, you have to understand exactly what it is that you're getting back.